# can i upload all data to gae without bulkloader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

i can use this code to download all data from my app on gae :

```
appcfg.py download_data  --application=zjm1126 --url=http://zjm1126.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=a.csv
```

it is not use bulkloader , so can i **upload** all data without bulkloader ,

thanks

Comment: download_data/upload_data are just frontends for the bulkloader. Why do you want to do this _without_ using the bulkloader?

Comment: cauz i want to download all kinds, not only a kind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `upload_data` command as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#(Deprecated)_Using_Code_for_Configuration), but this and your `download_data` command are deprecated from SDK 1.3.4 onwards. So it's better to look into using the bulkloader API as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html).